# Apache Redirect

Tags: apache

I have a question regarding redirecting to a specific page.  I have the following working

```
Redirect /inventoryForm /Form.html
```

Work flawless!  But, if the URL is

```
localhost/inventoryForm/form/test.... it goes to localhost/Form.html/form/test..
```

I only want it to go to Form.html if someone goes to /inventoryForm, regardless if they have form/test...etc

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using RedirectMatch , or mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias.
[RedirectMatch doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)

`RedirectMatch /inventoryForm /Form.html`

or
`RewriteRule /inventoryForm /Form.html [R=302]`